# How did the meaning of "consultant" shift from asker to askee?

Tags: etymology, semantics, derivational-morphology

Reading a different question about the opposite of the word *consultant* made we wonder why the word shifted semantically from the asker to the person who answers?

From Etymonline:

> consultant (n.)
>   1690s, "person who consults an oracle," from consult + -ant. In medicine, "physician called in by the attending physician to give consultation in a case," by 1872 (perhaps from French, where it was in use by 1867); general meaning "one qualified to give professional advice" is first attested 1893 in a Sherlock Holmes story. Related: Consultancy (1955).

The structure of the word suggests one who consults (others).

[Consult](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consult) means to ask or refer to. *e.g. Consult the experts.*

[-ant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ant?src=search-dict-box) (and its sister -ent) give the meaning of taking action or agency.

*Attendants* attend others. *Commandants* command others. *Regents* rule others. *Dependents* depend on others.  Etc.

How did *consultant* shift from the person asking to the person asked?

Comment: [Mirriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consultant) seems to be the only dictionary that offers "one who consults another" as the primary definition, although Oxford mentions it far down the page.

Comment: I spent awhile researching this online and could find nothing useful. I'm sorry.

Comment: I think you're mistaken in supposing that the "original" meaning of ***to consult** [with X]* was ***to take advice** [from X].* The full OED has as its first definition (first cite 1565) *To take counsel **together**, deliberate, **confer**; also said of a person deliberating with himself.* Which to my mind implies that right from the get-go there was always the possibility of *counsel / advice* going in either or both directions between the participants / "consultants".

Comment: As @FumbleFingers has pointed out, the meaning of the word has, from very early on, allowed it to be applied to both 'askers' and 'askees'. The reasons why we hear it applied to 'askees' far more often than to 'askers' are pragmatic: providing advice is something that one can do on a regular basis, as a profession, and there is thus a need for a convenient single word for those who practise such professions. One is an 'asker', on the other hand, only within the context of a particular transaction; it is not normally something that one practises as a profession.

Comment: @jsw29: Excellent point! Obvious once you explicitly set it down, but I wasn't consciously aware before of that reason why ***consultant*** would tend to gain more traction for ***askees*** than for ***askers***.

Comment: While I don't disagree with the answers on the subject of 'consultant', might someone not extend it by considering the (possibly American) word 'consult' (as a noun...the subject of the action I mean)? "I went for a consult." "He came to me for a consult."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Etymonline description is quite clear. The fact that originally the term was applied to “person who consults an oracle“ may create confusion.

Those who “consulted an oracle” were privileged people who had access to oracles whose opinions were often requested by ordinary people who wanted to know the views  and suggestions of oracles. In that sense the “consultant” was still someone  people relied on to have their advice.

In modern times, oracles disappeared but consultants remained.

> In medicine, "physician called in by the attending physician to give consultation in a case," by 1872

Comment: This makes the most sense. (As it was in line with my own supposition.) *Ask the consultant to find out the answer for us from the oracle ...*

Comment: Kind of like asking people on Stack Exchange, because they know how to use google to find the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Sherlock Holmes story in question is [Silver Blaze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventure_of_Silver_Blaze), one of the stories in the collection [The Memoirs of Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Memoirs_of_Sherlock_Holmes). Here's some of the context for the use of the word "consultant":

> Holmes shrugged his shoulders.  "There are certainly grave difficulties in the way," said he.  "[...] Might I ask for a photograph of Mr. John Straker?"
>
> The Inspector took one from an envelope and handed it to him.
>
> "My dear Gregory, you anticipate all my wants.  If I might ask you to wait here for an instant, I have a question which I should like to put to the maid."
>
> "I must say that I am rather disappointed in our London consultant," said Colonel Ross, bluntly, as my friend left the room.

Nobody came to Baker Street to get advice from Holmes; Holmes and Watson travelled to Devon to help in an investigation led by Insp. Gregory. It seems that Colonel Ross sees Holmes as someone who has come in order to ask questions. So his use of "consultant" is rather closer to the earlier sense quoted in the question: "physician called in by the attending physician to give consultation in a case", only transferred from medicine to another discipline.